# qmlRegisterSingletonType and multiple top-level windows

Tags: qt, qml

I have a `QGuiAppplication` derived class (called `Sy_application`) that I've wrapped with another (called `Sy_application_qml`, with extra some QML specific features) and then registered that as a singleton with the QML engine.

This all works fine from the first opened top-level window, but the second (and presumably any more) only gets `null` from the singleton.  Adding some debug:

```
// The static factory method used in the qmlRegisterSingletonType call.
QObject* Sy_application_qml::factory( QQmlEngine* engine,
                                      QJSEngine* scriptEngine )
{
    Q_UNUSED( engine )
    Q_UNUSED( scriptEngine )

    qDebug() << "Creating";
    return new Sy_application_qml();
}

// SY_APP is the qApp macro casted to my Sy_application type.
QObject* Sy_application_qml::get()
{
    qDebug() << "Getting:" << SY_APP;
    return SY_APP;
}

// This is an example of it's use within QML
onPositiveClicked: {
    console.log( Sy_application_qml );
    Sy_application_qml.get().newProject( sampleRate.value, frameRate.value );
    close();
}
```

And the debug output:

```
// Opening first window.
Creating

// Creating second
qml: Sy_application_qml(0x1895b30)
Getting: Sy_application(0x7fff80f051c0)

// Attempting to create third
qml: Sy_application_qml(0x1895b30)
Getting: Sy_application(0x7fff80f051c0)
qrc:/qml/gui/dialogs/Sy_newProjectDialog.qml:62: TypeError: Cannot call method 'newProject' of null
```

As you can see the singleton is still present and the C++ `Sy_application` instance is being returned correctly, but is appearing as `null` on the QML side.  Any reason why it works for one window and not another?

Comment: From doc: "In order to use the registered singleton type in QML, you must import the singleton type."  Are you doing this? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType

Comment: Also, really, have you tried to register Sy_application additionally? it looks like qmlRegisterSingletonType doesn't register your custom type

Comment: @N1ghtLight Yes I am importing it, otherwise the QML wouldn't compile.  I don't need to register `Sy_application` because I don't want to create any instances of it within QML; as it ultimately derives from `QObject` the QML engine can read it's properties without registration (which is why it works the first time).  In fact if I did register it as singleton type, another `Sy_application` would be created on the launching of the first window which would be *very bad*.

Comment: I meant to register with qmlRegisterType ... compilable example for this issue would be great

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, nor would it as I do not want to be able to instantiate another instance from QML.  You do not need to register a QObject derived type in order to access it's properties, if this wasn't the case it wouldn't work the first time.  My compilable example works fine, so there's something else going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally worked it out, and it had nothing to do with QML singletons or having multiple top-level windows - but it had everything to do with passing `QObject` pointers to the QML engine from `Q_INVOKABLE` methods (the `Sy_application_qml::get()` method in my case).

From the docs:

> Objects not-created by QML have CppOwnership by default. The exception
>   to this is objects returned from C++ method calls; in these cases, the
>   ownership of the returned objects will be set to JavaScriptOwnerShip.
>   Note this applies only to explicit invocations of Q_INVOKABLE methods
>   or slots, and not to property getter invocations.

So the QML engine had deleted my `Sy_application` pointer.  The solution was nice and simple:

```
QObject* Sy_application_qml::factory( QQmlEngine* engine,
                                      QJSEngine* scriptEngine )
{
    Q_UNUSED( engine )
    Q_UNUSED( scriptEngine )

    QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership( SY_APP, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership );
    return new Sy_application_qml();
}
```